# How to get ruby to show more decimal places?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, decimal

I'm currently doing a project Euler problem that requires me to find patterns in repeating decimals. However, Ruby rounds too soon and I can't find a way to flesh out decimals to the nth place.

For instance:

```
1/7.to_f => 0.14285714285714285
```

but I'm trying to make it so:

```
1/7.to_f => 0.14285714285714285714285714285757142857142857
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get as many repeating digits as you like, by scaling up the computation by a power of 10

```
10**100/7
=> 1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428
```

Answer (score 3):

All languages support being able to define the precision of floating point in output. Ruby uses the common format strings:

```
pi = 355.0/113.0
'%1.5f' % pi # => "3.14159"
```

Or, in your case:

```
'%1.20f' % (1.0/7.0) # => "0.14285714285714284921"
'%1.20f' % (1.to_f/7) # => "0.14285714285714284921"
'%1.20f' % (1/7.to_f) # => "0.14285714285714284921"
```

I'd recommend reading the documentation for String's [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-25) and [Kernel::sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf). How Ruby determines to use fixed or floating math and the uses of `to_f` is covered in any decent Ruby tutorial.

Comment: This is misleading, as doubles only have ~15 significant (decimal) digits. Obviously `'%1.30f' % (1.0/7.0) # => "0.142857142857142849212692681249"` doesn't contain the correct pattern

Comment: You are correct that beyond 15 it's questionable, however the point I was making is it's possible to format the number using sprintf's formatting strings. Feel free to add an answer to address various ways to increase the precision.